# Server.UrlDecode(...) umlaut results in �

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, sendgrid

In an .aspx page I want to read the filename from the request and want to save the original filename but have problems with the encoding.

i.e. the file with name `unnamedölßßöölölkä.png` has the encoded value of `unnamed�l����l.png` when trying to decode it using `Server.UrlDecode(file.FileName)`.

```
foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
{
    HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[fileName];
    string originalFileName = file.FileName; // this results in unnamed%F6l%DF%DF%F6%F6l.png
}
```

My goal is to get the original filename including the umlauts, why is Server.UrlDecode not working in this case?

`Request.ContentEncoding` is `utf-8`

Comment: That's the correct thing to do with `unnamed%F6l%DF%DF%F6%F6l.png` so the question is why it ends up with that in the first place. Does the HTML of the page the form is on have an encoding set?

Comment: Thanks for confirmation, The request is coming from SendGrid

Comment: When I URL encode `unnamedölßßöölölkä.png` it results in `unnamed%C3%B6l%C3%9F%C3%9F%C3%B6%C3%B6l%C3%B6lk%C3%A4.png`, different from what is in you inline comment, which cannot contain all characters of the file name, because it is too short.

Comment: Thanks for the help, your comments made it clear to me that the problem does not lie with how I encode the filename, but how I access the data coming from Sendgrid.